# In VBscript how do you call the first element of objFolder object type

Tags: vbscript

This is my first post and it is related to Vbscript. I am brand new to it, and I was able to hobble together two pieces of code I found on this site to get it to accomplish what I want, however I don't understand one section of the code and I'd like help if possible. Please see the code below, along with my confusion.

Basically this code looks at a particular directory and pulls out the name of a file in that directory. I then use this to open the file in Excel and convert the Excel to multiple csv files (one per tab in excel).

I added **** to the section I do not understand.  Basically I want to create an object that is simply the name of the 1 file in this directory. Apparently that doesn't seem possible in VBScript, as you ahve to create the object "objFolder.Files", which is a directt call to objFSO.Getfolder("directory).

I am confused as to what type of item this returns? It is not an array, yet it has multiple elements... I know it has multiple elements because I cannot assign a variable to it unless that variable is assigned inside of the FOR Loop.

NOte I assigned the variable "Brandon" inside the for loop in order to get the name of the file... How else could I do this?  Why do I need the For loop at all? I'd like to just grab the first 'element' of the objFolder.Files object.

Please let me know if my question doesn't make sense!

**CODE BEGINS HERE:**

```
Dim strFilename  
Dim objFSO  
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")  
objStartFolder = "C:\test files\population file"


Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)


Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

****For Each objFile in colFiles
    brandon=objFile.Name

Next

strFilename = objStartFolder & "\" & brandon  

If objFSO.fileexists(strFilename) Then  
  Call Writefile(strFilename)  
Else  
  wscript.echo "no such file!"  
End If  
Set objFSO = Nothing  

Sub Writefile(ByVal strFilename)  
Dim objExcel  
Dim objWB  
Dim objws  

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)  

For Each objws In objWB.Sheets  
  objws.Copy  
  objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\test files\csv files\" & objws.Name & ".csv", 6  
  objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
Next 

objWB.Close False  
objExcel.Quit  
Set objExcel = Nothing  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `GetFile()` method of the `FileSystemObject` to retrieve a specific [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strStartFolder & "\somefile.txt")
WScript.Echo objFile.Path
```

(BTW, I changed your `objStartFolder` to `strStartFolder`. It's just a string, after all, not an object reference.)

When you use the [Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property on a [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object, as you did in your example, you're returning a *collection* of `File` objects. Useful if you want to iterate all files in a folder.

If you know there's a single file in the folder, but don't know its name, you'll still need to iterate the `Files` collection. While VBScript collections *do* provide an `Item()` property, it doesn't allow the use of integer indexing. In other words, you *can't* do this:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files.Item(0)
```

You would need to use a `For Each ... In ...` loop, as you have done, and then exit after the first iteration.

```
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strStartFolder).Files
    strName = objFile.Name
    Exit For
Next
```

Comment: So i'm very new to programming (only use "sas" which isn't a real programming language).  So by definition vb Script returns a "collection" which is basically like a list with no specific order?  This implies by definition the need to loop over them...  That's actually very surprising to me. I'm kinda amazed you can't define a list of files within a directory, or create some kind of referentiable collection... Is there another method to do this? What if someone only wanted to grab the second to last file in a directory by created date? FYI your answer helpd a lot, will mark as correct!

Comment: Right, a collection is similar to an unordered list. The `Files` property doesn't guarantee a particular sort sequence. After all, what's right for you may not be right for someone else. Some may want it sorted by Last Modified Date, for example. So never assume there's any particular sort applied when iterating files in this fashion. You're free to sort them yourself, of course, using a VBScript sort algorithm or other means. Or you can use tools (like the `DIR` command) that _do_ have sorting options. But, inherently, collections do not have sorting capabilities.

Comment: If you wanted to travel down another road, however, you could use WMI and a WQL statement to query the files in a particular folder and also supply a sort sequence in your query. WMI and WQL are a little more complicated than using a `FileSystemObject`, however, but I can show an example of that method, if you'd like.